# How can I recursively use the Global in VIM?

Tags: vim, recursion, global

Is something wrong in ":g-2-g/3/" or is the recursion in the global just missing? I can not understand a reason for the error:

> E147: Cannot do :global recursive

How can I get a recursive global search in VIM?

**[Neil's initial Suggestion with the operator \| ]**

```
g/1.*2\|2.*1/
```

A disadvantage is that the combinations expand with n numbers. For three numbers, the number of combinations is 3! (=6) that is

```
g/1.*2.*3\|2.*1.*3\|3.*1.*2\|1.*3.*2\|2.*3.*1\|3.*2.*1/
```

For n numbers, the number of combinations is n!.

**[Solution with the operator \&]**

Brian Carper and Neil Butterworth figured out the solution. Great thanks for them!

```
g/.*1\&.*2\&.*3/
```

It is for the whole line:

```
g/.*1\&.*2\&.*3\&.*/
```

Comment: what is your example supposed to do?

Comment: Neil Butterworth: I choose every line with 2, then I I tried to choose 3 from every line of the last results.

Comment: isn't that the same as every line that contains 2 and 3?

Comment: Neil Butterworth: No. :g=12= won't match lines like "234oeu1" and "21". If the feature was in VIM, I could match them just by writing :g=1=g/2/. It matches every line with 1 and then every line with 2 from the last results. Clearly, it is different.

Comment: No, neil's right.  He wasn't saying every line that contains "23", just that they contain 2 and 3 somewhere.  Which is the same as what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New info:** This does what you want - the "\&" sequence is the "and" operator:

```
g/.*1\&.*2\&.*3/
```

Brian Carper's (see comments, and thanks again) explanation:

> `/1\&2/` wouldn't work because both
>   branches need to match "at the same
>   position". `/.*1\&.*2/` let the match
>   anchor itself at the front of the line
>   and then expand however much it needs
>   to to find the numbers

Comment: How would you do it with 3 numbers? g/1.*2.*3\|2.*1.*3\|3.*1.*2\|1.*3.*2\|2.*3.*1\|3.*2.*1/ Can you see that the number of combinations is n! for n number? The recursive global search would have only n number of combinations for n number. For n, it is just  :g-1-g/2/g@3@...g$n$. It would be cool!

Comment: \& is probably what you want, yes.  /1\&2/ wouldn't work because both branches need to match "at the same position".  /.*1\&.*2/ let the match anchor itself at the front of the line and then expand however much it needs to to find the numbers.