# Use global recursive from different functions in vimscript

Tags: vim

I want to use multiple globals in different functions in vimscript but I get the following error:

"Cannot do :global recursive"

To my problem: I have a config file with paths to multiple XML-files. I want to use a global for every path in the config file and a global for every tag in each XML-File.

So I have some thing like this:

> global search-for-a-file-path call functionX(filepath)
>
> functionX(filepath)
>
> edit filepath
>
> global search-for-tags call functionThatDoesStuff()
>
> functionThatDoesStuff()
>
> Stuff happens here...

Is there a possibility to make this work with globals or do I need to use a different approach?

P.S.: I already saw [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737078/how-can-i-recursively-use-the-global-in-vim) but it did not help me because I use the globals in different functions and the solution only shows how it is done in a "one-liner".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vimscript does simply not seem to be able to do it, so I came up with the following solution:

```
while search("the-thing-I-search-for") > 0
   call functionThatDoesStuff()
end while
```

My thanks go to [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341091/martin) for help on the matter.